# How can i add custom blocks in custom theme in magento 2.2.3?

Tags: magento2

i have created custom theme in magento 2.2.3 and i want to add some custom block to home page.Please help me how i can add or write code for that.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use below code in your Magento_theme template** :

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
          ->setBlockId('your_block_identifiers')
          ->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: thanks for replying...i will you what exactly i want to do. actually i want add a block which will be having two partitions one will be having normal banner and other will be having slider.

Comment: i have created new custom theme . so for adding custom block sholud i add code in default.xml?

Comment: @AnilBakale you should create two different block and can call add xml or phtml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add block from the admin side

> Content > Blocks

Create your block at here

> Content > Pages

Call that block in which page you want

Comment: thanks for replying. i have added normal blocks..just read my above comments, i want custom block...

Answer (score 0):

Create a **cms_index_index.xml** file in below path

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourCustomTheme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml

You can add custom block to homepage like below code

```
<referenceContainer name="content"> //You can change here as per your requirement  
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="customblock" after="-">
        <arguments>
             <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">yourblockIdentifier</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```